# Flutter: Stepper onStepContinue not firing

Tags: dart, flutter, stepper

Can you tell me what's wrong in my code?

```
Widget _createProfileStepper() {
int currentStep = 0;

List<Step> createAccSteps = [
  new Step(
    title: Container(),
    content: new Text('This is the first step.'),
    isActive: currentStep >= 0,
    state: currentStep >= 0 ? StepState.editing : StepState.disabled,
  ),
  new Step(
    title: Container(),
    content: new Text('This is the second step.'),
    isActive: currentStep >= 0,
    state: currentStep >= 1 ? StepState.editing : StepState.disabled,
  ),
  new Step(
    title: Container(),
    content: new Text('This is the third step.'),
    isActive: currentStep >= 0,
    state: currentStep >= 2 ? StepState.editing : StepState.disabled,
  ),
  new Step(
    title: Container(),
    content: new Text('This is the second step.'),
    isActive: currentStep >= 0,
    state: currentStep >= 3 ? StepState.editing : StepState.disabled,
  ),
  new Step(
    title: Container(),
    content: new Text('This is the third step.'),
    isActive: currentStep >= 0,
    state: currentStep >= 4 ? StepState.editing : StepState.disabled,
  ),
];

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Create Profile"),
  ),
  body: Stepper(
    type: StepperType.horizontal,
    currentStep: currentStep,
    onStepTapped: (step) {
      setState(() {
        currentStep = step;
      });
    },
    onStepContinue: () {
      setState(() {
        if (currentStep < createAccSteps.length - 1) {
          currentStep = currentStep + 1;
        } else {}
      });
    },
    onStepCancel: () {
      setState(() {
        if(currentStep > 0){
          currentStep = currentStep - 1;
        }
        else {
          currentStep = 0;
        }
      });
    },
    steps: createAccSteps,
  ),
);
}
```

I followed all examples for Flutter's stepper but still no luck. I can tap the continue button but it is not moving to another step. Did I forget something? I created a Stateful Widget class then a button would take me to call this _createProfileStepper(). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By having the entire code in `_createProfileStepper()` the widget becomes stateless even if it is used in a stateful widget. This is because whenever the `build` method of the stateful widget is re-running, it will call `_createProfileStepper()` which will cause the entire stepper widget to reinitialize i.e re-create the stepper, and thus the continue does not work.

Why not create a stateful widget for the step alone and use that widget instead of the one you're getting from `_createProfileStepper()`. For example:

```
class _SimpleWidgetState extends State<SimpleWidget> {
  int currentStep = 0;

  List<Step> steps = [
    Step(
        title: Text("Step One"),
        content: Text("This is the first step"),
        isActive: true
    ),
    Step(
      title: Text("Step Two"),
      content: Text("This is the second step"),
      isActive: true,
    ),
    Step(
      title: Text("Step Three"),
      content: Text("This is the third step"),
      isActive: true,
    ),
    Step(
      title: Text("Step Four"),
      content: Text("This is the fourth step"),
      isActive: false,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stepper(
        steps: steps,
        currentStep: currentStep,
        type: StepperType.vertical,
        onStepTapped: (step) {
          setState(() {
            currentStep = step;
            print(step);
          });
        },
        onStepCancel: () {
          setState(() {
            currentStep > 0 ? currentStep -= 1 : currentStep = 0;
          });
        },
        onStepContinue: () {
          setState(() {
            currentStep < steps.length - 1 ? currentStep += 1 : currentStep = 0;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SimpleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SimpleWidgetState createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _SimpleWidgetState();
  }
}
```

Then use `SimpleWidget()` where you would `_createProfileStepper()`

**Secondly**
As regards your question about your list accessing currentStep is because only `static` members can be used for initialization

Comment: Hi maker. I will try this suggestion and update you asap. Thanks!

Comment: Hi maker. I just included the stepper inside a scaffold because when it's in a container it produces an error. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

so you can't access your currentStep from inside list for starts.

"isActive" should be a boolean also (and only influences styling https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Step/isActive.html )

Also it seems a bit strange to have an empty Container() as a title, you could either remove it or put the step number in there

Try changing your Steps to

```
Step(
    title: Text("Step One"),
    content: new Text("This is the first step."),
    isActive: true
),
```

Comment: Hey Robbie. Do you know any reason why my list can't access currentStep? Also I think expressions that results to a boolean is okay with "isActive".  I also used placed an empty container because title is @required for step.

Comment: I found your question because I was looking for something similar, "How to modify 'state' on continue", my question was answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832710/how-to-modify-a-step-stepstate-on-continue which may solve your issue too, which [maker.jr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10437109/maker-jr) also answered.